# How to get request process condition on javascript using fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I use fetch API and when I make a request I show a loader on the screen. I would like to add also a progress bar that will load from 0% to 100% according to the request condition. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators - only with ReadableStreams in modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking of making a ajax loader like of gmail and other sites.
https://onextrapixel.com/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/